# Display products based on sub-categories

Tags: plugins

We need to display products in WooCommerce which are under the respective category in the sidebar of respective category pages, like this:

```
E-Books Categories
------------------------------------------------------
  -Product1
-------------------------------------------------------
  -Product2
```

Comment: Please put on more explanation to your question. Remember the more people here will understand, better the chance you have to get a solution.

Comment: i update question.  @ Maruti Mohanty

Answer (score 0):

you can register a new widget with your custom loop like this

```
<?php
add_action( 'widgets_init', 'Miy_widget_box' );?>
<?php function Miy_widget_box() {
register_widget( 'Miy_Widget' );
}?>
<?php class Miy_Widget extends WP_Widget {
    public function __construct() {
           // widget actual processes
parent::WP_Widget(false,'Title Widget','description=Description Widget');
    }
    public function form( $instance ) {
           // outputs the options form on admin
           echo 'include html coding in here';
    }
    public function update( $new_instance, $old_instance ) {
           // processes widget options to be saved
    }   
    public function widget( $args, $instance ) { 

    }
 }?>
```